# Like a Baby - Riddle

Tags: riddle, word

> I'm like a baby, 
>   but look out -I can bite!
>
> I depend on the milk you give me 
>   and I will be wherever you leave me.
>
> I love going outside with you 
>   as you push me in my stroller.
>
> Back and forth we walk 
>   over and over -like a cradle.
>
> All the while loving the smell. 
>   Oh. Need diaper change.

Who/What am I?

Comment: I can think of one thing that fits all this, and is I mean ***really*** like a baby . . .

Comment: @Rubio I suppose I intended the phrase "like a baby" to mean not actually a baby. Perhaps it should be known that its bite hurts a bit more than a baby's gums/teeth would

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are a

> Lawnmower

I'm like a baby,
but look out -I can bite!

> The blades of a lawnmower are usually very sharp.

I depend on the milk you give me
and I will be wherever you leave me.

> I think the 'milk' here is a metaphor for either oil or perhaps electricity.
>  Lawnmowers are generally inanimate so won't move from where you leave them.

I love going outside with you
as you push me in my stroller.

> This is the most convincing line for me, the act of pushing the stroller is similar to that of mowing the lawn.

Back and forth we walk
over and over -like a cradle.

> A common technique for mowing the lawn is to traverse back and forth over it in strips.

All the while loving the smell.

> The smell of freshly cut grass.

Oh. Need diaper change.

> When the bag is full you need to empty it, rather like a diaper change.